# Decrease month by one in strtotime?

Tags: php, strtotime

all

Decrease month by one in strtotime in this loop.

```
$twitter_val7 .='{
                            date: new Date('.date("Y",strtotime($date)).', '.date("m",strtotime($date)).', '.date("d",strtotime($date)).'),
                            value: '.$result_twitter->counts.'
                            },';
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To decrease by 1 month using `strtotime()` you literally tell it to decrease by one month:

```
strtotime($date . ' - 1 month');
```

Assuming, of course, that `$date` is a format `strtotime()` understands.

Comment: Look out with this function!!! It doesn't really subtract 1 month but 30 days. 31 May will end up as 01 May

Comment: @RJD22 it's not substract 30 day. Real logic is 
1) it decrease month number. From `2021-03-30` it become `2021-02-30`
2) then because `February` last day is 28th (and difference between 30 and 28 is 2 day) - it takes `2021-02-28` add to it `2 day` and now you have result `strtotime('2021-03-30 - 1 month') = '2021-03-02'`

Answer (score 4):

I would do it like this .. i guess `$date` would go in place of `'2000-01-01'`:

```
$initial = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
$interval = new DateInterval('P1M');
$newdate = $initial->sub( $interval );
echo $newdate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 1):

To decrease month by using strtotime

```
$date='2014-09-03';
$numMonth=1;//here you can pass no. of month
$resultDate=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date . " - $numMonth month"));
```

Comment: Please first understand the question, 6 vote answer question never be wrong

Comment: i am not say 6 vote answer wrong but it is another way to decrease month. $numMonth use as dynamic and return date as yyyy-mm-dd format.